# NSURL URLWithString the url is always nil

Tags: ios, nsurl

My code is like this :

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/FileAudit?user=%@&pass=%@&fileId=%d&isAudited=1&opinion=%@",appDelegate.user.userName,appDelegate.user.password,self.todo.fileId,self.opinion];
    NSLog(@"URL=%@",urlStr);        
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
```

And the url = (NSURL *) 0*00000000@"< nil >"

how can I work it out? thank you in advance!

Comment: If even one part of that string is nil, then the whole thing gets messed up.  Check that every one of its parts aren't nil.

Comment: Another reason could be a type mismatch, e.g., if `fileId` is an object and not an integer.

Comment: encode urlstring. [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Is it a existing sequence of your code? Or don't you call these strings in different places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging purposes, I would build up urlStr piece by piece instead of combining five NSStrings all at once. Put in an NSLog(@"%@", urlStr) statement after each addition to urlStr. This will reveal which piece of the puzzle is causing the problem.

Comment: I see , the self.opinion is NSString and it has some Chinese characters, so just like  0x8badf00d said , should be using NSUTF8StringEncoding ..Thank you all.

Comment: NSString *urlUTF8 = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlUTF8];